# angularjs $translate : get default translation in error handler

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have written this factory which will be called in case of any errors

```
app.factory('customTranslationHandler', function ($translate) {
    return function (caption, uses) {
        if(uses=='en') {
            var i = 0, strLength = caption.length;
            for(i; i < strLength; i++) {
                caption = caption.replace("_", " ");
            }
            var defaultText = caption.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
        } else {
            //var defaultText = $translate(caption).use('en');
            //var defaultText = $translate.instant(caption).use('en');
        }

        return defaultText;
  };});
```

If it is en, I format the caption and return it.
In case of any other language, I want to call translate for that caption using `en` as language. I get my translations from json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was set fallBackLanguage:

`$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');`